# Can't deserialize JSON with kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization, retrofit

I'm trying to use Retrofit to retrieve and deserialise a json response in the format below;

```json
{
    "com.ctrlart.jerusalemcardovr": {
        "id": "5306520532779265",
        "app_name": "JerusalemCardoVR",
        "is_available": true,
        "is_free": false,
        "is_demo": false
    },
    "com.johnraygames.mailroom": {
        "id": "5631025370338266",
        "app_name": "You've Got Mail - Stealth Office Simulator",
        "is_available": true,
        "is_free": false,
        "is_demo": false
    }
}
```

I have put together the two dataclasses below;

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class PackageInfo(
    val id: String,
    @SerialName("app_name")
    val appName: String,
    @SerialName("is_available")
    val available: Boolean,
    @SerialName("is_free")
    val free: Boolean,
    @SerialName("is_demo")
    val demo: Boolean
)

@Serializable
data class PackageData(
    val root: Map<String, PackageInfo>
)
```

My retrofit client below;

```kotlin
import com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.asConverterFactory
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object NetworkModule {
    private const val BASE = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()
        val json = Json {
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = false
        }

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(BASE)
            .addConverterFactory(json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
            .callFactory { okHttpClient.newCall(it) }
            .build()
    }
}
```

And finally my service and remote:

```kotlin
interface PackageService {
    @GET("$PATH/data/_apps.json")
    suspend fun getPackageData(): PackageData
}

class PackageRemoteImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val packageService: PackageService,
) : PackageRemote {
    override fun getPackageData(): Flow<PackageData> {
        return flow {
            emit(packageService.getPackageData())
        }
    }
}
```

I can see when adding a HttpLoggingInterceptor that the data is successfully being retrieved from the remote, though it never actually generates a flow of PackageData nor do I receive any kind of serialization error.

**EDIT 1**

RemoteModule

```kotlin
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object RemoteModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePackageService(retrofit: Retrofit): PackageService {
        return retrofit.create(PackageService::class.java)
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

I managed to resolve this, turns out the data source was returning a null value on a few entries on the is_available bool.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class PackageInfo(
    val id: String,
    @SerialName("app_name")
    val appName: String,
    @SerialName("is_available")
    val available: Boolean?,
    @SerialName("is_free")
    val free: Boolean,
    @SerialName("is_demo")
    val demo: Boolean
)
```

In addition to above, I also implemented the change required highlighted by Simon Jacobs.

```kotlin
interface PackageService {
    @GET("$PATH/data/_apps.json")
    suspend fun getPackageData(): Map<String, PackageInfo>
}
```

Now to figure out why the null Boolean result didn't raise a serialisation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Part 1: Serialization

When you use this:

```
@Serializable
data class PackageData(
    val root: Map<String, PackageInfo>
)
```

the library expects JSON of the form:

```
{
    "root": {
        "someKey": { /* some PackageInfo representation */ },
        "someOtherKey": { /* some PackageInfo representation */ }
    }
}
```

but you are actually passing JSON of the form:

```
{
    "someKey": { /* some PackageInfo representation */ },
    "someOtherKey": { /* some PackageInfo representation */ }
}
```

This is the JSON that is represented by `Map<String, PackageInfo>` by default, not `PackageData`.

You have two alternatives to fix this.

##### 1. Expect a different type

You could tell your HTTP client that you are expecting an object that deserializes to type `Map<String, PackageInfo>`, which presumably involves writing a different interface as follows (I am not familiar with your framework (edit: this does need further work; see part 2):

```
interface PackageService {
    @GET("$PATH/data/_apps.json")
    suspend fun getPackageData(): Map<String, PackageInfo>
}
```

##### 2. Change the `PackageData` serializer

Alternatively you can change the `PackageData` serializer. You can use the built-in `MapSerializer` and wrap it as follows:

```
class PackageDataSerializer : KSerializer<PackageData> {
    private val serializer get() = MapSerializer(String.serializer(), PackageInfo.serializer())
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor get() = serializer.descriptor

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): PackageData = PackageData(serializer.deserialize(decoder))

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: PackageData) {
        serializer.serialize(encoder, value.root)
    }
}
```

Then you can assign the new serializer to `PackageData`:

```
@Serializable(with = PackageDataSerializer::class)
data class PackageData(
    val root: Map<String, PackageInfo>
)
```

Now Kotlin serialization will expect the JSON you are transmitting.

#### Part 2: Retrofit

There look to also be some errors in your Retrofit setup.

1. Your `PackageService` should return an object of type `Call<PackageData>` rather than `PackageData`
2. Have you created your service on your built `Retrofit` object somewhere (ie the object returned from `provideRetrofit()`) as this is not shown? This would involve something like:

```
val packageService = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class.java)
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion as it was a really quick/easy change to make and test and unfortunately I'm getting the exact same result, it's like it's not even attempting to deserialize the json response. I also tried setting ignoreUnknownKeys to false as I know there are keys in the response I don't need so expected that to force a Serialization error but no error at all.

Comment: I had a look at the response headers and it looks like the server is sending text/plain rather than application/json... I'm guessing that's probably my issue, any pointers on where to start on fixing that would be immensely appreciated (I don't have control over the response type on the server).

Comment: I also looked at your retrofit setup which didn't look right: see edit. My hunch is the framwork might not be too fussy on the content type but that is just a guess

Comment: 1. I'm using this repo as a basis for building my app https://github.com/JayDev-Lee/GithubBrowserSample/blob/main/remote/src/main/java/com/jaydev/github/remote/GithubService.kt where they don't apply Call<T> to their service methods. 2. I've updated my main post to include details of how I'm creating and injecting the Package service.

Comment: I managed to figure this out, it turns out the is_available bool in the response can be null, so setting the data class field to Boolean? allowed me to get a deserialized response. What's more concerning is that I didn't get any kind of serialisation error to tell me that's what the issue was.

Comment: Well done. Note that you did need the above fix in your serializer.

Comment: Yes, your part 1 fix 1 (expect a different type) was also required. Thanks for that!